# Xamarin where is Id object

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I'm translating objective-c code to Xamarion.iOS.

In objective-c I have the following code.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown: (NSNotification*)aNotification
{
  NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
  CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboadFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
  . . .
}
```

The issue is that info objectForKey returns a Id object which has the method CGRectValue.

But in Xamarin I have...

```
private void KeyboardWasShown(NSNotification notification)
{
   var info = notification.UserInfo;
   var kbSize = (info.ObjectForKey(UIKit.UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey)).??
 . . .
}
```

In Xamarin the NSDictionary returns an NSObject, but the objective-c version returns an Id Object. NSObject doesn't have the method CGRectValue.

My question is what has Xamarin done with Id objects and what class should I cast to get the CGRectValue. I've tried casting to a UIView but that didn't help, unless I missed something.

I've tried googling for this but I just get a bunch of hits on iOSDevice Id's.

**Edit:**
I haven't had a chance to test this but I think I found a way to get to it possibly.

```
var kbSize = ((UIView) info.ObjectForKey(UIKit.UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey)).Frame.Size;
```

It will take me sometime before I get a chance to test if the object returned from that Id is of type UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xamarin, you can use the strongly typed notifications that will give you all you need without having to unbox data.

See the example here: http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIKeyboard/

In your case, instead of using `ObserveDidChangeFrame`, you want `ObserveDidShow`, but the idea is the same.

That said, if you still want to use the other approach, the value that comes out of the ObjectForKey call is an NSValue, so what you do is cast the result to NSValue, and then use the CGRectValue property.

Update: full link to the sample you want:

http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIKeyboard+Notifications.ObserveDidShow(System.EventHandler%7BMonoTouch.UIKit.UIKeyboardEventArgs%7D)/

Comment: Perfect! I was hoping there was a better solution then casting.